# How to cancel pull request in Sourcetree

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

Well, I tried to merge the *master* branch (red-one) and *statistics* (blue-one) via GUI client of Bitbucket. I'd like to update the *master* branch by *statistics* branch. But I made an opposite action. And now I have a commit with conflicts. I want to cancel this commit and corresponding pull request. How to do that via GUI? [image: repo view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `git checkout` on the previous commit where everything was still correct (*before doing the opposite action, `git-merge` wrong way*). On the command line that will looks like:

`git checkout 66dc132`

Make right click on this commit where before `git-merge` the wrong way, and then click on `Checkout`. [image]

Then you can make the `merge`-command the right way ;)